# How do I create PHP output based on form field input values?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php script that takes input values from a form and then outputs recommended trip routes when the form is submitted. I set the form method as POST. The issue is I'm getting a blank output.

I'm not sure if the issue is my code or the form POST method.

```
class Truck {
    // constructor
    public function __construct($truck_name, $max_weight) {
        $this->truck_name = $truck_name;
        $this->max_weight = $max_weight;
    }   
    public function print_truck() {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
               $truck_1 = new Truck($truck_name, $max_weight);
                  $this->truck_name = $_POST['truck_name'];
                  $this->max_weight = $_POST['max_weight'];
            }       
        echo $this->truck_name;
    }
} 

class Location {
    // constructor
    public function __construct($location_name, $location_weight) {
        $this->location_name = $location_name;
        $this->location_weight = $location_weight;
    }

    public function trip_1() {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $location_2 = new Location($location_name, $location_weight);
        $this->location_name = $_POST['location_2'];
        $this->location_weight = $_POST['package_2'];

    $location_3 = new Location($location_name, $location_weight);
        $this->location_name = $_POST['location_3'];
        $this->location_weight = $_POST['package_3'];
    }

    echo "Trip #1 \n" . $this->location_2 . ", " . $this->location_3 . "\n";
    }

    public function trip_2() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $location_1 = new Location($location_name, $location_weight);
        $this->location_name = $_POST['location_1'];
        $this->location_weight = $_POST['package_1'];
    }
    echo "Trip #2 \n" . $this->location_1;
    }
}

# Here's the output HTML:
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Deliveries</title>
</head>

<body class="container">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="truck_name" Placeholder="Truck Name" value="" required>
  <input type="number" name="max_weight" Placeholder="Max weight in lbs" value="" required>
  <h4>Delivery Locations</h4>
  <input type="text" name="location_1" Placeholder="Location 1" value="" required>
  <input type="number" name="package_1" Placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>  
  <input type="text" name="location_1" Placeholder="Location 2" value="">
  <input type="number" name="package_2" Placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>
  <input type="text" name="location_1" Placeholder="Location 3" value="" required>
  <input type="number" name="package_3" Placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Trips">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { ?>
    <h2><?php echo "Trip Routes"; ?></h2>
<?php
   $truck_1->print_truck();   
   trip_1();
   trip_2();
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the expected result:

Trip 1: 
location 2, location 3

Trip 2: 
location 1

Comment: Put an else conditions for if(isset($_POST['submit']) in side that else echo something by doing this you come to know weather there is successful POST request or not.

Comment: I don't have the option to edit the question. How else can i share the form html?

Comment: you can edit the question, look carefully and you will find the links

Comment: Does your form have an action

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti I added the else condition, still getting blank output.

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks, I found it. I've now added the form html.

Comment: @jameson2012 The form doesn't have an action. I was thinking it doesn't need one since the php code is in the same file as the form html

Comment: Aren't trip_1() and 2 methods of the location class?

Comment: Your code makes little sense and should throw a bunch of undefined variable warnings. Example, in your `print_truck()` method, if `isset($_POST['submit'])` is true, you create a new class instance and are passing two undefined variables to the constructor. After that, you never even do anything with that class instance? You then do the same in the other methods as well...

Comment: @jameson2012 yes they are. is it wrong to call them as I did, even as public functions?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I forgot to mention that I'm a newbie at php. I would appreciate any help or advise in the right direction :)

Comment: Also, when you call `$truck_1->print_truck();`, where did you define `$truck_1`? And where are the functions `trip_1()` and `trip_2()`? There are too much strangeness here. I would recommend going though some basic PHP and OOP tutorials.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `trip_1 ()` and `trip_2()` are defined as public functions within the `class Location` object. I'll go ahead and rework the code.

Comment: But you're not calling them as methods on a class instance. You're calling them as stand alone functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't instantiate any of your classes before trying to call the methods.  You need to instantiate the class e.g $truck = new truck(); and th n call your methods from there.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment ( then deleted ) and has been pointed out - the above code does not really make much sense. I appreciate that you are learning PHP but the manner in which the class objects are instantiated and assigned values is not correct. Having the `class constructor` called in a class `method` is back to front. The `class` should be instantiated with whatever parameters are required and then it's `methods` called. A class can be given as an argument to another class - which is sort of what I did below where I created a new class called `Trip` and assigned an instance of the `truck` and `location` .... I have likely missed the point but hope it helps a little.

```
<?php

    class Truck {
        private $truck_name;
        private $truck_weight;

        public function __construct($name=false, $weight=false) {
            $this->truck_name = $name;
            $this->max_weight = $weight;
        }
        public function get_name(){
            return $this->truck_name;
        }
        public function get_max_weight(){
            return $this->max_weight;
        }
    }


    class Location {
        private $location_name;
        private $location_weight;

        public function __construct($name=false, $weight=false) {
            $this->location_name = $name;
            $this->location_weight = $weight;
        }
        public function get_location(){
            return $this->location_name;
        }
        public function get_location_weight(){
            return $this->location_weight;
        }
    }

    class Trip{
        private $truck;
        private $locations;

        public function __construct( Truck $truck, $locations=array() ){
            $this->truck=$truck;
            $this->locations=$locations;
        }
        public function display(){
            if( !empty( $this->locations ) ){

                $dots=str_repeat('-',25);

                printf(
                    "<h2>Trip Routes</h2>
                    <pre>%s\nTruck: %s\nMax-Weight: %s\n%s\n",
                    $dots,
                    $this->truck->get_name(),
                    $this->truck->get_max_weight(),
                    $dots
                );

                $total_locations_weight = 0;

                foreach( $this->locations as $index => $location ){
                    $total_locations_weight += floatval( $location->get_location_weight() );
                    printf( 
                        "[Drop: %d]\nLocation: %s\nLocation-Weight: %s\n\n",
                        $index+1,
                        $location->get_location(),
                        $location->get_location_weight()
                    );
                }
                printf("%s</pre>",$dots);

                /* Is there too much weight for the truck? */
                if( $total_locations_weight > $this->truck->get_max_weight() ){
                    printf(
                        "<pre><h1 style='color:red;margin:0;'>Maximum Weight Exceded</h1><div>Total weight is: %s</div><div>Limit exceded by: %s:</div>\n%s</pre>",
                        $total_locations_weight,
                        $total_locations_weight - $this->truck->get_max_weight(),
                        $dots
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Deliveries</title>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
      <form method="post" action="">

        <input type="text" name="truck_name" placeholder="Truck Name" value="" required>
        <input type="number" name="max_weight" placeholder="Max weight in lbs" value="" required>

        <h4>Delivery Locations</h4>

        <input type="text" name="location_1" placeholder="Location 1" value="" required>
        <input type="number" name="package_1" placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>  

        <input type="text" name="location_2" placeholder="Location 2" value="">
        <input type="number" name="package_2" placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>

        <input type="text" name="location_3" placeholder="Location 3" value="" required>
        <input type="number" name="package_3" placeholder="Package weight in lbs" value="" required>


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Trips">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
      </form>

    <?php


        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

            $truck_name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'truck_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $max_weight = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'max_weight', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            $location_1 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'location_1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $location_2 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'location_2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $location_3 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'location_3', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            $package_1 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'package_1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $package_2 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'package_2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $package_3 = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'package_3', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );







            $truck=new Truck( $truck_name, $max_weight );

            $loc_1=new Location( $location_1, $package_1 );
            $loc_2=new Location( $location_2, $package_2 );
            $loc_3=new Location( $location_3, $package_3 );

            $trip=new Trip( $truck, array( $loc_1, $loc_2, $loc_3 ) );
            $trip->display();
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And typical output might be:

```
Trip Routes
-------------------------
Truck: The Crushinator
Max-Weight: 2500
-------------------------
[Drop: 1]
Location: London
Location-Weight: 1500

[Drop: 2]
Location: Glasgow
Location-Weight: 1500

[Drop: 3]
Location: Edinburgh
Location-Weight: 550

-------------------------
Maximum Weight Exceded
Total weight is: 3550
Limit exceded by: 1050:
-------------------------
```

Comment: thanks for this. it has definitely given me an idea for what i need to work on to get the expected output. I'll update soon with the final result. Thanks again!

Comment: I would like to display 2 locations under one trip. like `$trip_1=new Trip( $truck, $loc_1, $loc_2 );
            $trip_1->display();` How can I do that with your code setup?

Comment: `" it has definitely given me an idea for what i need to work on to get the expected output"` ... really? Have you tried to apply any of the above ( which, incidentally, was not intended to be the actual code but more of a suggestion ) and if so - where is it? The original code was so flawed as to make it worthless virtually ( sorry ). You could, perhaps, as a suggestion only - supply MANY locations in an array/object as the 2nd argument to the `Trip` class and process that??!?

Comment: I know very well your code was a suggestion. I used it as a guideline to properly instantiate my functions. Here's how i setup my with magic `__set` and `__get` methods. `Trip` class: `class Trip{
private $truck;
        private $location;
        public function __construct( Truck $truck, $locs=array() ){
            $this->truck=$truck;
            $this->location=$locs;            
        }   }`. initialized: `$trip_1 = new Trip(array("location1" => "$loc_1"));
$trip_1->location1;` My prev question wasn't well worded. I'm only trying to see where i'm getting the array process wrong.

Comment: sorry if last comment sound a bit irritable - I was. Anyway, modified above - perhaps it'll help but it's likely I missed the point again.